# Webpack loading entire library (Kendo UI) rather than individual components?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, webpack

After analyzing my gargantuan 20MB webpack bundle, I've found that Kendo UI (v 2016.3.1028) is taking up ~10 MB:

```
C:\Projects\webpack-angular-es6-master>webpack --json | webpack-bundle-size-analyzer
kendo: 9.92 MB (62.7%)
font-awesome: 1.27 MB (8.04%)
angular: 1.13 MB (7.15%)
angular-material: 1.08 MB (6.82%)
jquery: 251.51 KB (1.55%)
angular-ui-router: 165.89 KB (1.02%)
angular-animate: 147.1 KB (0.908%)
toastr: 29.11 KB (0.180%)
angular-sanitize: 26.26 KB (0.162%)
angular-aria: 14.87 KB (0.0918%)
style-loader: 6.99 KB (0.0431%)
css-loader: 1.47 KB (0.00907%)
webpack: 84 B (0.000506%)
<self>: 1.79 MB (11.3%)
```

I've created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/TimeBomb006/b9fc4d7add48b006cf47f0219e09f164) to show my webpack config, index.js (Angular entry point), and controller.js.

The key excerpts are, I believe:

index.js.. registering the Kendo directives:

```
import 'kendo.core';
import 'kendo.angular';

...

angular.module('app', [uirouter, sanitize, home, post, 
                      comment, user, adverseEvent, 
                      product, 'ngMaterial', 'kendo.directives'])

...
```

And controller.js.. importing the Kendo grid module so that it can be used on the associated page as `<kendo-grid></kendo-grid>`:

```
import 'kendo.grid';

...
```

Is my configuration incorrect from the details provided? Is there more info needed?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include the full kendo JS(kendo.all.min.js) if you don't need it.

You are free to only include the individual JS for the components you use(i.e. kendo.grid.min.js AND kendo.dropdownlist.min.js, etc).

Or, you can generate a custom JS file that includes all the components you use.

See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need

This may also be of interest: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/webpack

Comment: I've found that if I omit the kendo.core and kendo.angular imports in index.js (thus only importing kendo.grid on the controller) then Angular seemingly can't instantiate the <kendo-grid/> directive. I'll review the documentation you've included, thanks.

Comment: You will always need the core library plus whatever widgets and dependencies you want to use.  I think there is a difference between the imports and which JS is included in the bundle.  It looks like you are bundling the entire, big kendo library into the pack so that you can import/use only core, angular, and grid...but I think you can get away with just bundling core, angular, and grid to import core, angular, and grid.

Comment: Now that you say that, it seems very obvious that this is what I'm doing, but I'm not experienced enough (despite reading the docs) with Webpack to know which configuration is at fault. I assume something in the webpack.config.js file is causing the entire bundle to be loaded. Potentially something wrong with https://gist.github.com/TimeBomb006/b9fc4d7add48b006cf47f0219e09f164#file-webpack-config-js-L56 ?

Comment: I don't use Webpack but looking at their docs and the kendo webpack docs, you may be able to use the single entry configuration(entry: filename) to bundle select, individual files instead of everything in the folder OR remove the files you don't want from the kendo/js folder and then the mass bundling should only contain the kendo files you left in the folder.